Is this proof of Arden's Theorem correct?
Arden's Theorem: Let $P$ and $Q$ be regular expressions over $\Sigma$ such that $P$ does not contain the null string. Then, the equation $R = Q + RP$ has a unique solution $R = QP^*$.
Proof: Substitute $R$ by $Q + RP$ in the given equation.
We get $R = Q + (Q + RP) P = Q + QP + RP^2$.
Substitute $R$ again: $ R = Q + QP + (Q+RP)P^2 = Q + QP + QP^2 + RP^3$.
Continuing this substitution we get:
$ R = Q + QP + QP^2 + QP^3 + ... = Q (\epsilon + P+P^2+P^3 + ... ) = QP^*$.
Question: Is this proof correct? I know that the condition that $P$ does not contain $\epsilon$  is needed for the theorem to hold, but I do not see where the proof uses this fact.

The proof is very sloppy, and if it shows anything, it shows that $R=QP^*$ is a solution, but nothing about uniqueness.

That $\dots$ is kinda sketchy.  Like where did the $RP^n$ term go?

That is also the part I am confused about. Can we just repeatedly substitute $R$ infinitely..?

Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/170242/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4993712/14578.  Please do not post the same question on multiple sites.

I gave a detailed proof of Arden's rule  here.

Here is a rigorous proof. And you will see where the $\varepsilon\notin P$ comes into play.
Our goal is to show that $R=Q+RP$ with $\varepsilon\notin P$ implies $R=QP^*$.

Well, let us first show that $QP^*\subseteq R$. To do this, we will show that $QP^j\subseteq R$. The required result will immediately follow.
We proceed by induction. For $j=0$, we have $Q\subseteq Q+RP=R$ and thus the base case holds. Assume it holds for $j$. Then for $j+1$, we have $QP^{j+1}=QP^jP\subseteq RP\subseteq Q+RP=R$ and this finishes the induction step.

Now for the converse, we want to show $R\subseteq QP^*$. We will induct on the length of words of $R$. So let $x\in R$. For the base case, we need to check all words of the smallest length in $R$. Let it be $a$. Then $x\in R$ implies $x\in Q$ or $x\in RP$. If $x\in Q$, then clearly $x\in QP^*$. If $x\in RP$, then $x=yz$ with $y\in R, z\in P$. But since $\varepsilon\notin P$ we have $z\ne \varepsilon$ and thus $|y|<|x|=a$ which is a contradiction. Thus this case cannot occur. This finishes the base case.
Assume we have shown this for all words of length at most $n$. Then let $x\in R$ with $|x|=n+1$. Then again $x\in Q$ or $x\in RP$. If $x\in Q$, we are done. If $x\in RP$, then $x=yz$ with $y\in R, z\in P$ again with $z\ne \varepsilon$. Thus $|y|<|x|=n+1$ implying $|y|\le n$ and thus $y\in QP^*$. Thus $x=yz\in QP^*P\subseteq QP^*$ and this finishes the proof for the converse.

By basic set theory now, $R=QP^*$.

Edit : If $\varepsilon\in P$, then there are more solutions. But they can be characterized easily.
Areden's theorem (extension) : If $R=Q+RP$ and $\varepsilon\in P$, then the solution set of $R$ is $$\{AP^*\mid A\supseteq Q\}$$
Proof : This is simpler actually. First let us show that any element of that set is actually a solution. Well, first note that since $\varepsilon\in P$, we have $P^*=P^+$ implying $AP^*P=AP^+=AP^*$. Also $Q\subseteq A\subseteq AP^*$ and thus $$Q+RP=Q+AP^*P=Q+AP^*=AP^*=R$$
Conversely, we show that these are all solutions. Suppose $B$ is a solution. Then $B=Q+BP$ implying $Q\subseteq B$. Also since $\varepsilon\in P$, we have $Q\subseteq B\subseteq BP$ and hence $B=Q+BP=BP$. By induction $B=BP^n$ for all $n$, implying $B=BP^*$. Since $B\supseteq Q$, this is inside that set. We are done.

Thank you for your answer. I wanted to check one more thing. At the end (theorem extension), shouldn't it be $Q + RP = Q + AP^P = Q + AP^ = AP^* = R$, or did I misunderstand something in this part?

@36n You are right! I made a typo, now edited. Thanks
